# Is there any solution about asp.net core mvc switch route without refresh page like angular route reuse strategy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp-net-core-spa-services

i just want to achieve the following results,switch route without refresh page
[image]

**supplement:**
i want to keep the page state
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this function **partial view**.

Here is a simple demo for your reference:

HomeController:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult FirstTab(string param)
        {
          return PartialView("_FirstTab",param);
        }

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Page2</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> 
        @Html.Partial("_FirstTab", "Page1")
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @Html.Partial("_FirstTab", "Page2")
    </div>
</div>
```

_FirstTab.cshtml partial view:

```
@model string

<h1>This is the @Model Tab</h1>
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: i add a supplement,it's not work for me,and i think it's not good idea,if i got 10+ tabs,the page will be too large

Comment: @Jarvan, If most of your tabs have the same structure, then you only need to create a public partial view and pass in different parameters. I updated my post, you can refer to it.
But if each of your page structure is completely different, then you must create a partial view for each tab page, which is unavoidable.